# Postgresql: Multiple indexes or one concatenated index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have a partitioned table for everyday of the month: day_01, day_02 and so on.

Each table have in average 5 million records.

I have 3 fields I filter in almost every query:

```
fk integer
enum integer
value character varying(50)
```

and another one that contains all the previous ones concatenated

```
values_concat character varying(150)
values_concat = fk || '|' || enum || '|' || value
```

**Is it better to use a multi-column index with (fk, enum, value) or a single index with (values_concat)?**

- *fk* references a table with ~50000 records
- *enum* is an enum with 300 possible values
- *value* is almost unique and has a length of ~20

Comment: If `value value is almost unique`, and your queries use `=` (equal) operator against this column, then create the index on this field because it has the highest selectivity. If you are planing to delete rows from referenced table, or update FK calue in the referenced table, then also create an index on FK column - the delete and updat causes a scan on referencing table for rows matchin the old value, the index will speed this operation up, more on this you can find [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html)

Comment: @krokodilko cool, thanks. But without the context, just with the question: is often better to create a multi column index with 2 integers and 1 text, or just one bigger string?

Comment: If all queries use `=` operator and the index is "almost" unique, then this one index is enough - each query will pick only 1-2 or maybe 3 unique rows. If you are using range operators`>` '`<`  or `LIKE 'constant%' ` against this column, then things get complicated  - it depends on concrete query.